# Testing for a condition in recursive loop and adding

Tags: javascript, recursion

So here's the challenge I'm trying to solve:

A "Cool Number" is defined as a number where the sum of the squares of each of it's digits eventually reach 1.

ex: 23

**2**^2 + **3**^2 = 13
1^2 + 3^2 = 10
1^2 + 0^2 = 1

*NOTE: All "non-cool" numbers will eventually return 4 in their series and loop infinitely.*

Find all "cool numbers" from 1 to 1,000,000 (inclusive). Then add them up.

Here's my code. It works but when I post my sum (70601040511), it is getting rejected by the host server. Maybe you see something here I don't?

```
function isCool(int){

  var intArr = [];
  var squareArr = [];
  var sumOfSquares = 0;

  function numToArr(num){           //split int into separate digits
    var arr = num.toString().split("");
    var res = [];
    var len = arr.length;

    for (i=0; i<len; i++){
      res[i] = parseInt(arr[i]);
    }
    return res;
  }

  function getSquareArray(){      //get the square of each digit in array
    var res = [];
    var len = intArr.length;

    for(i=0; i < len;i++){
      res[i] = Math.pow(intArr[i],2);
    }
    return res;
  }

  function getSumOfSquares(){    //get sum of squares in int array
    var res = 0;
    var len = squareArr.length;

    for (i=0; i < len; i++){
      res += squareArr[i];
    }
    return res;
  }

  intArr = numToArr(int);
  squareArr = getSquareArray(intArr);
  sumOfSquares = getSumOfSquares(squareArr);

  if(sumOfSquares === 4){
    return false;
  } else if (sumOfSquares === 1){ 
    return true;
  } else {
    return  isCool(sumOfSquares);  //call function on itself until 4 or 1 is reached
  }

}
```

Sum all cool numbers up to and including given limit

```
function getCoolNumbers(limit){
  var limit = document.getElementById("num").value;
  var res = [];

  for (var i = 1; i<=limit; i++){
    if(isCool(i)===true){
      res.push(i);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("coolarray").innerHTML = res;
  return res;
}

var coolSum = 0;

function sumCoolNumbers(){
  var res = 0;
  var arr = [];
  var limit = document.getElementById("num").value;
  arr = getCoolNumbers(limit);
  var len = arr.length

  for(var i = 0; i<len; i++){
    res += arr[i];
  }
  coolSum = res;
  document.getElementById("coolsum").innerHTML = "= " + res;
  document.getElementById("coolquant").innerHTML = len + " Cool Numbers"
}
```

Comment: Don't you have a mistake in your example at `1^2 + 3^2 = 10`?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by _"My sum is getting rejected"_?

Comment: What is the expected (final sum) answer? When I ran your code the sum was 70,601,040,511; when I [wrote my own code](https://jsfiddle.net/nj93o6nv/) from scratch I got the same result. Having said that, most of your functions have a mistake where they ignore the argument that was passed and instead either use a variable defined outside the function or get a value from an HTML element - luckily this problem doesn't actually affect the result because those other values are the same as the arguments. Your code would be easier to debug if you fixed those issues.

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb Sorry for the lack of clarity. The challenge poses that I should find the sum of the "cool numbers" and make a POST request to an API. If the sum is correct, it will return a set of letters. However, my sum is getting rejected after trying to execute the POST request. My hunch is that my sum is wrong.

Comment: @nnnnnn My expected answer is also 70601040511. However, as part of the challenge I have to make a POST request to an API with this number. However its getting rejected with a responsetext of "not a cool number." My assumption is that I made a mistake somewhere in either generating the "coolnumber" or the sum. Also, thanks for your feedback. I tried to markup some simple HMTL for practice but it isn't necessary for debugging this problem. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Fabien 1^2 = 1, 3^2 = 9, 9 + 1 = 10

Comment: By my calculations 70601040511 is both the sum you need *and* a cool number in its own right, so if the API rejects it with the message "not a cool number", to me that implies a problem in the code that calls the API, not a problem with your calculations. (Or a problem with the API itself.) Perhaps you should edit the question to show *that* code.

Comment: @nnnnnn Makes sense. Not sure what it is though. This is my first crack at calling an API so its likely I'm making a mistake somewhere I'm not seeing. If you want to take a look at the code challenge I'm trying look up http://dev.getethos.com/ and run devtools and check out the hidden <p> tags. It lays out the rules of the challenge. Also that JSFiddle is beautiful. Hopefully I can write code like that some day.

Comment: Ha, thanks. It could be made better, I just wanted it to work. The code at the following fiddle doesn't work from the JSFiddle site, but *does* work if you paste it into the console while on the dev.getethos.com page: https://jsfiddle.net/e916oyL0/ - it's just a hacked-together way to submit the answer to all the /codeX URLs, simplified with jQuery (a library that is, conveniently, already included on that page).

Comment: When I then take the resulting word and enter it into the field on the dev.getethos.com page I get this response: "Cool you got the code right! However, you submitted the request as an unauthorized user... Try again!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@nnnnnn made some good comments and you should address the issues he/she highlights. To go along @nnnnnn and @PeterJacuzzi, I also wrote my own version of `isCool` and arrived at the same result of `70600040511`

Whether that's the correct answer, I don't know. But 4 people (including you) arrived at the same answer based on your specification of the problem.

So I'm not really sure how this answer will help you other than showing you different ways to approach the problem – and maybe some space/time considerations.

```js
const digits = x =>
  x < 10
    ? [x]
    : digits (x / 10 >> 0) .concat ([x % 10])

const add = (x,y) =>
  x + y
  
const sum = xs =>
  xs.reduce (add, 0)
  
const sq = x =>
  x * x
  
const isCool = x =>
  x === 1 ? true :
    x === 0 || x === 4 ? false :
      isCool (sum (digits (x) .map (sq)))

const time = (s, f) =>
  (console.time(s), f(), console.timeEnd(s))

time ('without memo', $ => {
  const xs =
    Array.from(Array(1e6), (_,x) => x).filter(isCool)
  console.log('count %d; sum %d', xs.length, sum(xs))
})
// count 143070; sum 70600040511
// without memo: 6558.235ms
```

Here's a memoised version which takes more space but runs in less time

```js
const digits = x =>
  x < 10
    ? [x]
    : digits (x / 10 >> 0) .concat ([x % 10])

const add = (x,y) =>
  x + y
  
const sum = xs =>
  xs.reduce (add, 0)
  
const sq = x =>
  x * x
  
const isCoolMem = (memo => {
  const readwrite = (x, f) =>
    memo.has (x)
      ? memo.get (x)
      : (memo.set (x, f (x)), memo.get (x))

  const aux = x =>
    readwrite (x, y =>
      y === 1 ? true :
        y === 0 || y === 4 ? false :
          aux (sum (digits (y) .map (sq))))

  return aux
}) (new Map ())

const time = (s, f) =>
  (console.time(s), f(), console.timeEnd(s))

time ('with memo', $ => {
  const xs =
    Array.from(Array(1e6), (_,x) => x).filter(isCoolMem)
  console.log('count %d; sum %d', xs.length, sum(xs))
})
// count 143070; sum 70600040511
// with memo: 2667.815ms

time ('with memo, round 2', $ => {
  const xs =
    Array.from(Array(1e6), (_,x) => x).filter(isCoolMem)
  console.log('count %d; sum %d', xs.length, sum(xs))
})
// count 143070; sum 70600040511
// with memo, round 2: 488.205ms
```

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. Seems like my API call was getting rejected, so my problem might be lying there and not in my code (which is somewhat reassuring). But seeing different, leaner, solves for this problem is very helpful.